# Help me understand how to Find f(n)

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have this question:

- $f(0) = 0$
- $f(1) = 1$
- $f(n) = f(n-1) + f(n-2)$

help me understand and find $f(n)$.

Comment: Fibonacci function. Should be a duplicate.

Comment: This falls in the area of recurrence relations.  You can search for that to find general methods of solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you know [Fibonacci](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number) rabbits?

That's a famous recurrence relation that we can solve by trial solution in the form $f(n)=x^n$ that is

$$x^{n}=x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}\implies x^2-x-1=0 \implies x_{1,2}=\frac{1\pm\sqrt 5}{2}$$

then

$$f(n)=c_1x_1^n+c_2x_2^n=c_1\left(\frac{1+\sqrt 5}{2}\right)^n+c_2\left(\frac{1-\sqrt 5}{2}\right)^n$$

and from the initial conditions $f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=1$ we obtain

- $c_1+c_2=0\implies c_1=-c_2=c$
- $c\left(\frac{1+\sqrt 5}{2}-\frac{1-\sqrt 5}{2}\right)=1\implies c=\frac1{\sqrt 5}$

and finally

$$f(n)=\frac1{\sqrt 5}\left(\frac{1+\sqrt 5}{2}\right)^n-\frac1{\sqrt 5}\left(\frac{1-\sqrt 5}{2}\right)^n$$

and indicating with $\phi=\frac{1+\sqrt 5}{2}$ the golden ratio we have that $\frac{1-\sqrt 5}{2}=-\frac1{\phi}$ and thus

$$f(n)=\frac1{\sqrt 5}\left(\phi\right)^n-\frac1{\sqrt 5}\left(-\frac1{\phi}\right)^n=\frac{\phi^{n}-(-\phi)^{-n}}{\sqrt 5}$$

Comment: no..............

Comment: 0,1,1,2,3,5,8,...read about it :)

Comment: ok thanks I live in stupid country we dont study these things

Comment: @Wel the Fibonacci sequence is possibly the most recognised sequence in the world! Questions like *Find the next number in the sequence $1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8$* even pop up in IQ tests :)

Comment: I would interpret "find $f(n)$ as "find the general term of $f(n)$".  In this sense, I don't think this is an answer.

Comment: @Wel I can't belive it! ;)

Comment: @Wel Take a look also here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dTWKKvlZB08

Comment: @Wel You are welcome, do not hesitate to ask for any other clarification about the derivation for a general expression, also form the other OP. Bye

Comment: @GNUSupporter In the link given there is also the derivation, I can't also derive it there but I think it should be useless.

Comment: You can, but you *won't* since it's an PSQ.  IMHO, I don't think that the link YouTube video can help OP understand why there's a golden ratio between two adjacent terms of Fibonacci sequence.

Comment: @GNUSupporter The video is just for curiosity, I'm referring to the wiki link given in the answer. There are all the information there. Thanks

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/983396)

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco Did you read what the OP wrote there? He wrote "thanks for all the help", then maybe my answer was useful for him. The link I gave contains all the necessary information, I could copy and paste it but it should be completely useless.

Comment: It's a link only answer. Expand it or it will be removed. Moreover asking rhetorical question as answer is a poor idea as it is likely to trip up reviewers.

Comment: @quid I've expanded the full solution, whitout copy and paste!

Comment: Thank your for the expansion.

Comment: @quid I really thought it wasn't necessary but it's ok, thank for your suggestion. Bye

Comment: @gimusi looking back at my answer, I did not realise you used the same link in your comment! Very sorry for unintentionally stealing your comment. Do you watch Numberphile too?

Comment: @user477343 Don't worry for that! It's a kind of classical derivation, indeed at first I only gave the linj but then I was requested to expand. I did directly to review the subject! Bye

Answer (score 3):

Adding to @gimusi 's answer, if you divide $f(n+1)$ by $f(n)$, then this approaches a certain value, for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. We will call this value $v$, then $$\frac{f(n+1)}{f(n)}\operatorname*{\longrightarrow}^{n\to\infty} v,$$ or $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{f(n+1)}{f(n)} = v.$$ Whichever choice of notation you prefer. After going [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dTWKKvlZB08), we find that $$v^2 - v - 1 = 0.\tag{In the link, $v = \Delta$}$$ Do you know the quadratic formula? If so, you can apply it to this equation and obtain that $$v = \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2} = \color{orange}{\verb|The Golden Ratio|}\tag{denoted by $\varphi$}.$$

This is why the sequence you have, known as the **Fibonacci Sequence**, is very well-known!